# How to forward headers from aws cloudfront when origin is s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-headers, amazon-cloudfront

I m trying to leverage browser caching for my website in order to please "google page speed check".

google complains that there is NO expiration date defined in my images so I m trying to add a `"cache-control" header` to my images. I m serving the images via `Amazon cloudfront` and the origin is `S3`. I read several articles and the steps I m following are:

1. I go to my `s3` bucket and manually set a `"cache-control" header`
   for my test object (image). I works and I can see the header in my browser.
2. I go to my CloudFront distribution, `"behaviour" -> "edit"` and
   from there I ve tried the following things:

   a) set `"Forward Headers" to "all"`. Amazon complains that `"all"` value
   cannot be set when origin is `s3`.

   b) set `"Forward Headers" to "Whitelist"` -> Add `"Origin"` as
   whitelisted header. It doesnt work. When I check my browser I dont
   see the `"cache-control" header`

   c) set `"Forward Headers" to "None"` -> and `"Object Caching"` to "Use
       Origin Cache Headers". It doesnt work.

   d) set `"Forward Headers"` to `"None"` -> and `"Object Caching`" to
   `"Cusomize"` -> Specify a value for min/max/default TTL . It doesnt
   work.

So I ran out of options and hope. Any ideas how can I achieve letting `CloudFront` forward the headers to the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're not waiting for the changes to propagate. I have been using the below configurations successfully.

[image]

Post this, just wait for the changes to propagate. (if you're so impatient, then create a `*` invalidation)

To upload assets, you can use the following command [Assuming that you have aws cli downloaded].

```
aws s3 sync local_dir s3://bucket --cache-control max-age=604800
```

Comment: Yes you re right Karan, I invalidated my object and then worked perfectly! As a follow- up I m trying to also enable gzip compression on cloudfront. For that I added a "Content-Length" header in the object and set the "Compress Objects Automatically" to "Yes" as instructed by several articles/blogs on aws. However, the object is not compressed. Maybe you have an idea about this?

Comment: You just have to check the option to cache objects automatically from CloudFront, no need to change it in S3

Comment: And similarly, you will have to wait again :)

Comment: Actually, I did waited and also invalidated the object already...Anyway I ll wait bit longer

Comment: Maybe you can post this as as different issue if it doesn't resolve.

Comment: @panipsilos how are you confirming that the object is not being compressed?  The problem could be with your test methodology.

Comment: @ Michael, I m checking the response headers in my browser. "Content-Encoding: gzip" should be there right? My browser sends the "Accept-Encoding : gzip" header. Also I m running the google page speed check.
@Karan, right I ll post it as a different issue

Comment: @panipsilos I found your [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41967632/1695906) but I didn't get notified of this comment.  To tag a user, you need to ensure you have no space after the `@` and you will want to include their username but with no spaces, e.g. `@michael-sqlbot`.  Let's see what we can find for you on that new question...