# How to enable gzip compression on AWS CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip, amazon-cloudfront

I m trying to gzip compress the img I m serving through `CloudFront`. My origin is `S3`

Based on several articles/blogs on aws, what I did is:

1) Set `"Content-Length"` header for the object I want to compress. I set the value equal to the size appeared on the `size` property box

2) Set the  `Compress Objects Automatically` value to `Yes` in the `Behaviour` of my cloud distribution.

3) I invalidated my object to get a fresh copy from `S3`.

Still I m not able to make `CloudFront` gzip my object. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I'm trying to gzip compress the [image]

You don't typically need to gzip images -- doing so saves very little bandwidth, if any, since virtually all image formats used on the web are already compressed.

Also, CloudFront doesn't support it.

See [File Types that CloudFront Compresses](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html#compressed-content-cloudfront-file-types) for the suported file formats.  They are text-based formats, which tend to benefit substantially from gzip compression.

If you *really* want the files served gzipped, you can store the files in S3, already gzipped.

```
$ gzip -9 myfile.png
```

This will create a gzipped file `myfile.png.gz`.

Upload the file to S3 **without** the .gz on the end. Set the `Content-Encoding:` header to `gzip` and set the `Content-Type:` header to the normal, correct value for the file, such as `image/png`.

This breaks any browser that doesn't understand `Content-Encoding: gzip`, but there should be no browsers in use that have that limitation.

Note that the `-9`, above, means maximum compression.

Comment: Hi Michael, thnx for your reply. I mainly want to increase the score in the google page speed check.

Comment: @panipsilos gzip offers improvements for text based resources: HTML, JS, CSS, not images

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to gzip jpegs/pngs, I would suggest that you first compress them online with a tool such as https://tinyjpg.com/

You will not need to compress the images further ideally. Compressing images with image optimization tools will work better than using `gzip -9` as it takes into consideration the textures, colors and patterns and such.

Also, make sure that you save your file in the proper formats (actual images in jpg and vector images in png) - This will help in reducing the size of the images

Comment: Thnx Karan, I ll give it a try

Comment: @panipsilos Do let us know what worked as I feel compressing images with image compression techniques will work much better than gzip as it's better equipped to compress textual information.

Comment: Hi Karan, you re right it doesnt worth using gzip. for now i used some online tools for compressing png/jpg files. Google page speed check stopped complaining.

Comment: @panipsilos then you can accept my answer as correct :)